# How should I install NFS on a linux system?

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs

I have two systems and I need to setup a folder on one of them that is completely read/write-able by the other.

Questions:
1) How do I setup NFS on the server(s)? It is not installed as an available filesystem/module.
2) Where should I place this folder / what is the conventional place for locating such shared folders?

This is a RHEL5 system.

---

Error with setting up NFS.

This is what I did on server1 on which I want to share a local folder with server0

1. In /etc/exports , I added
   /home/els1-share 199.199.82.98(rw,sync)
2. mkdir /home/els1-share
3. Enabled nfs and portmap through
   ntsysv
4. Started services:

/etc/init.d/portmap start
Starting portmap:                                          [  OK  ]

/etc/init.d/nfs start
Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS quotas:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS mountd:                                       [  OK  ]

Now, on server0, I did
1. mkdir /home/els1-share
2. mount 199.199.82.130:/home/els1-share /home/els1-share

which timed out with:
mount: mount to NFS server '199.199.82.130' failed: System Error: Connection timed out.

The IP addresses have been obfuscated, otherwise the output is exact.

Answer (score 4):

```
yum -y install nfs-utils portmap
```

Prepare and modify /etc/exports for sharing files, that would similar to as shown below

> /home/NFS-files
>   192.168.100.0/24(ro,sync)
>
> /home/NFS-share */26(rw,sync)
>
> /ISO 192.168.100.0/24(ro,sync)

```
service portmap start

service nfs start
```

Comment: Hi - this is on the server on which the folder exists locally? What do I have to do on the server which is accessing this share?

Comment: if you have 192.168.100.20 nfs server and you have share /data folder which you want to mount to 192.168.100.21 so run the following command $mount 192.168.100.20:/data /nfs-data and then df -h  http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/05/fedora-nfs-server-configuration.html

Comment: Hi. It didnt quite work... can you have a look at the edit please?

Comment: @TWord: Do you have a firewall enabled? Check out the output of "iptables -vL" -- also if you have SELinux enabled (check that with "getenforce"), it can deny all sorts of things.

Comment: Hi Janne - it gives a lot of output / what exactly should i be looking for? This is on RHEL5.

Answer (score 1):

the common placement of NFS exports is outside any os controlled areas ( /usr /etc /var ) usually in another area called /exports

If you are automounting home directories under /home this will change your placement.

Usage of the **showmount -e**  to verify is very helpful.

Enjoy.
fe007

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have also started nfs and portmap on the client. To test NFS works, turn of the firewall on both servers temporarily if possible with the command:

```
service iptables stop
```

Comment: woah... would doing "service iptables start" get things back to normal??